# Detect when a child form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8

I have he following Form:

- An Initialize Function that is called when the Form1 is created.
- A button that opens another Form (Form2)

What I need is to call `Initialize()` not only when Form1 is created, but whenever Form2 is closed, since Form2 might have modified some stuff that makes `Initialize` need to be called again.

How can I detect when the form2 is closed?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        // Read a config file and initialize some stuff
    }

    // Clicking this button will open a Form2
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2().Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // some stuff that Form2 does which involves modifying the config file
    }
}
```

Comment: When Form2 is opened, are the users still allowed to access Form1 or do they have to wait until Form2 is closed ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to call back to original form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876459/how-to-call-back-to-original-form)

Comment: @redParrot Why doe you write the same link 2 times in 2 different comments ?

Comment: Users should not continue to use form1 while form2 is opened, so I'll make it a modal form as suggested by @Idle_Mind

Comment: That is why I asked, yes in that case opening Form2 as modal is the best solution

Comment: But, when the answer if @Idle_Mind is the one you will go for, why did you mark the other answer as accepted ?

Comment: One of them added automatically. Thanks for notifying me. @GuidoG I removed one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add an event handler for the FormClosing event, this handler could be in your first form class and here you can call every internal method of that class

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.FormClosing += childClosing;
    form2.Show();
}
private void childClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Initialize();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Steve's excellent answer, you may consider displaying Form2 as a **modal dialog**. This would mean code execution in Form1 STOPS until Form2 is dismissed. This may or may not work well with your application, we have no idea what it does.

At any rate, you'd use [ShowDialog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead of `Show()` like this:

```
// Clicking this button will open a Form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2().ShowDialog(); // <-- code STOPS here until form2 is closed
    Initialize(); // form2 was closed, update everything
}
```

Comment: that's useful thanks. Form2 is basically a graphical editor of the config file, that's why when it closes I have to reinitialize some things in form1, since it might have changed some config parameters